# After effects MP4 render problem

Tags: after-effects

On after effects I have been having a problem with rendering as when i try to render a video with a regular 3.2 PAR (Pixel aspect ratio) after effects resizes it from MP4's 1920x1080 to 720x1080 and this is really bad for the video quality, i have tried changing the PAR to 5.1 and this does stop the resizing but it makes my video quality terrible, Please help me if you can.

Comment: Why would you want to render with a PAR of 5:1? Of course it's going to look dodgy, you're reducing the horizontal resolution 80%. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: because i heard it would help in this question with a simalar problem http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/adobe-after-effects-mp4-export-issue?newreg=c438d6fff6d44f3a865a522d353e5190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing pixel aspect ratios with image aspect ratios.

I suspect you want square pixels - ie a pixel aspect ratio (PAR) of 1:1

Most HD videos are 1920x1080, which is an image aspect radio of 1.778 to 1.
Most HD videos have a pixel aspect ratio of 1:1.

Is your desired image size actually 1280x720 ?  I suspect it is, rather than 720x1280 (720 horizontal x 1280 vertical).

Non-square pixels are only usually used for SD widescreen videos - more of a legacy requirement these days.  Unless maybe you're designing for a specific custom display like a big advertising screen or something like that?

Comment: I'm sorry but all i need the video to be 1920x1080 because that is the size that fits perfectly on youtube and also it is the size that my DSLR films in, In the past i have been able to easily render as mp4 with no video quality problem or resizing, i cant help thinking I've accidentally done something with my settings to cause this error.

Comment: what camera are exporting from - what are the specifications of your original footage?

Comment: 25 fps   1920x1080  1080p       Cannon EOS 1200d

Comment: never mind sorry you were right!